# NonAsync method going throw Async for single flow calls

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await, .net-standard

I'm creating a .NET Standard library with several methods, each having regular and async version.

So one method for example is:

```
public static int DoSomethingOne(string value) { ... }
public static async Task<int> DoSomethingOneAsync(string value) { ... }
```

Now they are doing some string manipulation and also calling DB with EF functions.

Currently I have these methods in complete separate flow but I have seen example of internal methods being joined meaning non async going throw async with `if` condition and returned with `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();`
This approach seems more DRY, no double code.

So the question: is that structure valid or should I stick to separate flow?

Also to note that I already have segments of logic in shared methods that are async agnostic, but still some code is doubled, like calls to those shared method and few other lines.

To extend the example:

1. Currently have:

```
public static int DoSomethingOne(string value)
{
    return DoSomethingOneInternal(value);
}

public static async Task<int> DoSomethingOneAsync(string value, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await DoSomethingOneInternalAsync(value, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private static int DoSomethingOneInternal(string value)
{
    var input = DoStringChangeOne(value);
    CallDbOne(input);
    var output = DoStringChangeTwo(input);
    var count = CallDbTwo(output);

    return count;
}

private static async Task<int> DoSomethingOneInternalAsync(string value, CancellationToken cancellationToken) { ... }
{
    var input = DoStringChangeOne(value);
    await CallDbOneAsync(input).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var output = DoStringChangeTwo(input);
    var count = await CallDbTwoAsync(output).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return count;
}
```

2. Alternatively could write:

```
public static int DoSomethingOne(string value) 
{
    return DoSomethingOneInternalAsync(value, null, isAsync: false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

public static async Task<int> DoSomethingOneAsync(string value, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{
    return await DoSomethingOneInternalAsync(value, cancellationToken, isAsync: true).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private static int DoSomethingOneInternalAsync(string s, CancellationToken? cancellationToken, bool isAsync)
{
    var input = DoStringChangeOne(value);

    if(isAsync) {
        await CallDbOneAsync(input).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    else {
        CallDbOne(input);
    }
    var output = DoStringChangeTwo(input);
    var count = isAsync ? await CallDbTwoAsync(output).ConfigureAwait(false) : CallDbTwo(output);

    return count;
}
```

Now there are around 10 method like this, and they have 2 to 4 depth levels of calls to internal submethods for better structure.
Also to add that async version are 'main' ones and more often used as to why they have direct flow, while nonAsync are not regularly used so they are redirected in option 2.

Comment: Stick to separate flow. Think about it. You could just make synchronous versions and then make the async ones wrap the sync ones with `Task.Run`. Either way, they are both shortcuts which break natural or organic asynchronicity. Sure there will be "double code", but you eliminate potential deadlocks which can arise from `.Result`. At the end of the day, this is an opinion, which isn't what Stack Overflow is for... so, take it for what it's worth.

Comment: For best practices in `async/await` land, spend a day reading Stephen Cleary's blog

Comment: @Andy thx for quick answer, will keep it separate, only do some more refactor to make as clean as possible.

Comment: @Andy take a look at this: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) Spoiler alert, the answer is no.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias -- i know this -- I said not to do that. It breaks the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is that structure valid or should I stick to separate flow?

It's [valid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development). Whether you should use it or not is up to you. The benefits of the "boolean argument hack" is that your code is DRY - in particular, this means that if there's a bugfix applied to one method, then both the synchronous and asynchronous versions always get that bugfix. But if these are relatively small methods, then the extra boilerplate may not be worthwhile.